# API Call after user selection

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, selection

Um Currently working on an old angular js application.

This has a series of checkboxes where the user can select an option/ several options. for every selection, it does a backend api call. but I want to avoid making a backend call for every selection but allow the user to do his selection for a couple of seconds and then do a backend call at once. I tried to achieve it via a $timeout function, even though it wait for a couple of seconds until the user does the selection, but it does call for the backend API for the number of time I select/deselect the options.

plunker : [sample plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3vPtLoMH54QpW1vY?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

much appreciate if someone could suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just keeping track of whether you are waiting to call the backend. If you are waiting, don't call your function again. Untested code example:

```
var waiting = false
$scope.toggleCheck = function (option, optionArray, channel) {
    var index = optionArray.indexOf(option);
    optionArray[index].checked = !(optionArray[index].checked);
    if (waiting == false) {
        waiting = true //set to true so backend will not be called multiple times
        $timeout(function () {
            waiting = false
            //call the backend api
            //access the statuses by $scope.statuses
            alert('backend call ' + $scope.statuses);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a debounce function. Given a delay in ms, calling the debounce function will start a timer and execute after the timer has reached 0. If we call the same function again, before the timer has reached 0, the timer restarts.

This will prevent the backend from being spammed with API calls if the user frequently clicks the checkboxes.

For more information about debounce, please check out this link (where throttle is also explained): https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: @Dark99 no problem :)